# Visual Studio 2017 cant clear chrome browser cache

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome

I'm noticing that when I debug websites with Visual Studio 2017 I cant clear the chrome browser cache.  Old versions of the code and cookies remain after I go into the Chrome history and clear all the items. I was using Visual Studio 2013 and had no problems clearing the cache.  Has something changed in the debugging with chrome?  Do I need to somehow clear the cache within VS 2017?

Thanks

Pete

Comment: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/debug-aspnet-incognito-mode-and-avoid-cache-issues

Comment: Thanks for the tip